# Python json.load() takes forever

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, count

I am writing a python code (python 2.7.6) to count the number of tweets which contains the target keywords.  For some tweet json files, it works perfectly fine.  For some other problemtaic tweet json files, the script will stuck in the python json.load() for hours and not finished.

There are still 2 GB memory remaining in the job monitor after hours of executing.  So i don't think it is a memory issue.  IMHO there are issues in the json file since it is a messy live tweet data.   I am trying to find json validators to confirm my hypothesis. I have tried to use jsonlint but it just generates weird error messages which cannot find any solution on Google (other post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731844/jsonlint-error-message-throw-new-rangeerrorattempt-to-allocate-buffer-larger).  COuld any guru enlighten?  Thanks!  Any solution or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like the script is stuck at tweet = json.loads(line).  It takes forever. Still analyzing the issue

Comment: Perhaps your second file is corrupt somehow? Did you create the 700MB file by duplicating the 100MB file multiple times, or was it obtained completely independently? In the latter case, the file itself might be problematic, and I would try with a duplicated 100MB file first.

Comment: Probably no longer fits in RAM and is swapping to disk.  Try watching your disk throughput under both test cases.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The second file was obtained completely independently. I download the live tweets and save them into each file everyday.  Smaller files work fine and the larger ones as mentioned are not.

Comment: I try to use jsonlint to validate these json files but encounter some error messages.  I post the question here.  Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731844/jsonlint-error-message-throw-new-rangeerrorattempt-to-allocate-buffer-larger